# Verifying keyboard input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been writing a Python 3 program that includes a keyboard input and I wanted to test what comes in, to make sure it meets certain criteria, namely it should be a single character and only a, b or c.
Being new to Python, I have cobbled together some code from other pages here, and it seems to work, but I'm not sure that it follows best practice (or even is correct programming). So any comments/improvements or alternatives most welcome.

```
chars = set('abc')
trigger = 0
while (trigger == 0):
    answer = input(':')
    if len(answer) != 1:
        print ('Please enter only one character')
    if any ((c in chars) for c in answer):
        trigger = 1
    else:
        print ('please answer a,b or c')
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If you're unsure, delete the question and go and **test it**. If you are aware of a specific problem, [edit] to provide a [mcve]. In general, the guidance on validating user input is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response.

Comment: Many thanks, the link you provided took me to what I was looking for, although I hadn't come across that page in my searches.

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of valid inputs, and use `in` to test. Example:

```
>>> rv = input()
a
>>> rv in ['a', 'b', 'c']
True
>>> rv = input()
test
>>> rv in ['a', 'b', 'c']
False
```

Comment: You would also have to add `len(rv) == 1' for multi-char input

Comment: @JoeIddon That is not necessary. As you can see in the second try, a string with a length > 1 fails. If you tried `'aa' in ['a', 'b', 'c']` it would also fail.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, I assumed you were using the `in` operator on a `string` in which case you would have to check it was length `1`, my bad!

Comment: Of course `len(rv) == 1 and rv in 'abc'` is also a valid answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your help folks, I had a feeling there was a better way